# Set default home page in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser

How do I create a link to set the user's home page to my URL?

Answer (score 7):

As some people have already answered, it used to be possible in internet explorer (prior to IE 7 I believe, could be wrong though) using something similar to

```
document.setHomePage('www.example.com');
```

I don't think any browser supports it anymore though. However, I would definitely try to convince you to do otherwise. Most people won't like having their settings automatically changed, even if it's triggered by a mouse click or other action. It's also quite likely that overzealous 'protection' programs will jump all over it and stamp it as a malicious attack.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it's just possible in Internet Explorer

```
Make my Page your
<a href="javascript:history.go(0)" onClick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';
 this.setHomePage('http://www.test.de');">Startpage</a>.
```

Comment: This seems to work fine in IE7 with the exception that I got a "reload/retry" warning with the page I was using.  I changed it to `href=""` and that fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean put a link in your page to make it the browser homepage? In IE you can do something like:

```
this.setHomePage('http://www.mysite.com');
```

I don't think that works in Firefox though.