# How to set default browser throw asp.net , c#.net code and Mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, default

i have a web application using asp.net, c# and MVC3.

I want to set my website as default home page to all browsers when i click the link button of my web site. how i can done it ? using code ?? plz help me ..

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript . Answered 2 years back :)

Comment: As far as I know you can do it only with Javascript. 
Look here - http://scripts.tropicalpcsolutions.com/html/javascript/save-website-as-homepage-javascript.html

Comment: @Dmitry Kotov he is asking about setting the homepage ... indeed a duplicate

Comment: @V4Vendetta, thanks for comment. I've update my link. One more link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438108/set-default-home-page-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that anymore since IE6 or 7. I don't think it ever worked in Firefox and other browsers. IE used to have a `document.sethomepage()` method.