# Is it possible with html ,jquery or any other web language to create link to make current page as home page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set default homepage in FF and Chrome via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946189/how-can-i-set-default-homepage-in-ff-and-chrome-via-javascript)

I want to create some script or code for a link so that when someone clicks on that link my website become his/her homepage (sorry for bad English).

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://www.websitegoodies.com/tools/homepage.php
This may depend on the browser however. 
`<a href="#" onClick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';this.setHomePage('twythm.com');">Clicky</a>`

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438108/set-default-home-page-in-javascript). The answer is that it's possible in IE using `this.setHomePage(url)` but can't be done in other modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:if(document.all)window.external.AddFavorite(location.href,document.title);  
else if(window.sidebar)window.sidebar.addPanel (document.title,location.href,'');">Bookmark this page</a>
```

Check this link for details : http://www.hostingfanatic.com/webdev/add-to-bookmarks-javascript/