# How do I create a link to set the user's home page to my URL for all browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set default home page in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438108/set-default-home-page-in-javascript)

How do I create a link to set the user's home page to my URL for all browser?

Comment: this i have already tried but only works for Internet Explorer...and what about other browsers...

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. It used to be possible in older version of Internet Explorer, but thankfully they removed that.