# Is setHomePage still supported in Internet Explorer 11 and/or Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I want to give the visitors of my website the choice to set their homepage to my website. In the past it was possible to use the SetHomePage function. Has the function changed or is it deprecated?

Comment: Last time I saw that function working was in IE6 or something, it's very likely gone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438108/set-default-home-page-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

SetHomePage is no longer supported.  Due to malicious behavior, there is no current equivalent for JavaScript, however, there is a [C++ interface](https://web.archive.org/web/20110222191120/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531405(v=VS.85).aspx) available to IE BHOs and extensions.  (This interface is presumably not available to MS Edge.)

[SetHomePage](https://web.archive.org/web/20110222191120/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531405(v=VS.85).aspx) was implemented as part of the legacy binary behaviors library, [introduced with IE5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffdav/archive/2004/04/13/112632.aspx). (Note that the linked blog post describes changes made more than ten years ago.)   It was deprecated in IE9 and made obsolete with IE10, though you could still call the feature from document modes that supported it.  Support was finally removed with the [release of IE11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801216(v=vs.85).aspx).

To my knowledge, there is no standards-based equivalent feature.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance